# Return single property with spring-boot repository

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Today I use spring-data-jpa to create my queries.
Is it possible to return only one property from the object?
For example:

```
public interface UsuarioRepository extends MongoRepository<Usuario, String> {

    String findNameByMailAndPassword(String mail, String pass);

}
```

I want to return only the name, not the whole `Usuario` object.

Comment: What you did should work, at least it works for sprign-data-jpa. Ddi you try it already ?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB only returns JSON documents for standard queries.You can try @Query.The fields property in @Query will cause only the fields set to 1 being returned.

```
public interface UsuarioRepository extends MongoRepository<Usuario, String>

  @Query(value="{ 'mail' : ?0, 'pass' : ?0 }", fields="{ 'name' : 1}")
  Usuario findNameByMailAndPassword(String mail, String pass);

}
```

This will return only the name and Id properties of the Usuario objects.